# How to store api-keys for AppDelegate.swift securely

Tags: ios, flutter, key, api-key

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps
import flutter_local_notifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    // Todo: Add your API key here
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
    }

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I am making a flutter mobile app and above is my ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift file.
Now i need to provide it Gmap api key but from another file which would be .gitignored so my api-keys arent published on my Version Control.

I have done something simmilar on Android by storing keys under:
android/app/src/main/res/values/keys.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as storing something securely on a client application. Malicious users can always decompile the code and retrieve your API key.

Instead, you can do your best to secure using this Google Maps API key in the Google Cloud Console by constraining it to be used only by the apps with the Application ID (Android) and Bundle ID (iOS) you define: [API security best practices - Set an application restriction for an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#application-restriction)